# How to set environment variables in GitHub actions using python

Tags: python, continuous-integration, environment-variables, github-actions

I want to execute a python script to set some environment variables in GitHub actions. I want to use those environment variables later in my GitHub actions steps. My python script looks like:

```
new_ver = get_version_from_commit(commit_msg)
if new_ver:
    if new_ver == "false":
        os.environ["SHOULD_PUSH"] = "0"
        print("Not pushing the image to k8s")
        exit(0)
    else:
        new_tag = app_name + ":" + str(new_ver)
        os.environ["DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG"] = new_tag
        os.environ["SHOULD_PUSH"] = "1"
        print("New tag: " + new_tag)
        exit(0)
```

Part of my GitHub actions file, after the execution of the above python script looks like:

```
- name: Print env var
  run: echo ${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG }}
- name: Build and push
  id: docker_build
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
     push: true
     tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG }}
```

But using os.environ won't expose the environment variable outside of the python process. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot set environment variables directly. Instead, you need to write your environment variables into a file, whose name you can get via `$GITHUB_ENV`.

In a simple workflow step, you can append it to the file like so (from the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)):

```yaml
echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

In python, you can do it like so:

```py
import os

env_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_ENV')

with open(env_file, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("MY_VAR=MY_VALUE")
```

Given this python script, you can set and use your new environment variable like the following:

```yaml
- run: python write-env.py
- run: echo ${{ env.MY_VAR }}
```

Comment: why do you need write into a file "a"? how does it write for file "a"?

Comment: "a" is not the filename, but the mode. It means open the file in append mode.

Comment: ah, yeah! That is true, I see the code now, thank you

Comment: Does this work today?

Comment: Note: `myfile.write(...)` does not append a newline, whereas `print(..., file=myfile)` does. So `print` is the correct equivalent to `echo "..." >> $GITHUB_ENV`.

Answer (score 4):

I asked me how to set two or more environment variables. You have te seperate these variables with a linebreak. Here is an example:

```
import os

env_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_ENV')

with open(env_file, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("MY_VAR1=MY_VALUE1\n")
    myfile.write("MY_VAR2=MY_VALUE2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, maybe more straightforward, way is to print a value in your Python code and "catch" it on the bash level, after which you can append it to `GITHUB_OUTPUT` variable -

*script.py*

```
def main():
    print("SOME VALUE")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*workflow.yml*

```
- id: set-variable
  run: |
    YOUR_VARIABLE=$(python script.py)
    echo "YOUR_VARIABLE=${YOUR_VARIABLE}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
- name: Use your variable
  run: |
    echo "Your variable value is ${{ steps.set-variable.outputs.YOUR_VARIABLE }}"
```