# Github actions: use env variable on another env variable?

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to reuse some common variables that act as bases for other variables. But I'm not sure how to reuse it.

In my workflow I tried this:

```
env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  MY_REPO: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/versada/monodoo
  MY_MAIN_TAG: ${{ env.MY_REPO }}:16.0
```

If add this, what happens weirdly is that my workflow is entirely ignored and not run at all. No errors, nothing. I would expect to at least get some kind of error, saying something is not right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read environment variables in env section of github action workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72206656/how-to-read-environment-variables-in-env-section-of-github-action-workflow)

Comment: According to accepted answer, I guess it is not supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, concatenation doesn't work (yet?) at the environment variable level. You will have to use the `$GITHUB_ENV` variable in a step to achieve what you want at the moment. I've made an example [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/53-concatenation.yml).

Comment: In GitHub Actions, you cannot use one environment variable to define another environment variable directly within the `env` block of your workflow file. This limitation is causing your workflow to be ignored without any error messages. To reuse variables, define basic variables at the workflow level, then reference and combine them within each job's steps using shell commands. For creating dynamic variables during the workflow, use step outputs or define environment variables within a step, which later steps can use.