# new format of output in custom GitHub Actions since set-output is going to be deprecated

Tags: github, github-actions

As per GitHub's recent announcement, github action's `set-output` is going to be deprecated next year. I was able to use the new format (`echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`) in workflow file, and it works. But we also have a **custom GitHub action(private one) written in python** and we are also using `set-output` there in `main.py` as:

```
                output_matrix = json.dumps(jsondata)
                print(f"::set-output name=output_matrix::{output_matrix}")
```

What I have tried so far is :

`print(f"output_matrix = {output_matrix} >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT")`

but this doesn't seem to help. Any solution how we can use `set-output`'s new format inside custom github action python file.

Comment: You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70123328/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-github-actions-using-python/76391502#76391502) post where a few working options are given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a test [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3282142781/jobs/5405134970) using this [workflow implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester64.yml) and this [python script](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/new-output.py).

What you can do in a **python script** is the same implementation for outputs variables as for environments variables.

**Example for ENVIRONMENTS variables:** ([here is another topic about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70123328/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-github-actions-using-python))

```
import os

env_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_ENV')

hello='hello'

with open(env_file, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(f"TEST={hello}")
```

**Example for OUTPUTS variables:**

```
import os

output_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_OUTPUT')

hello='hello'
    
with open(output_file, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(f"TEST={hello}")
```

*Note that this implementation was working even before the update regarding the `::set-output` depreciation.*